# Applying pod network (calico) end with "unable to recognize.." "no matches for kind"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to build a local bare metal kubernetes cluster on ubuntu.

Following step by step guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWg3ORRRF60) I've managed to install kubernetes master and have got the success message "Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!" after initializing the cluster with 'kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.0.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.0.0.20' command.

Now the next step is to deploy a pod network so I have used calico,
running the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml --validate=false
```

And I get the output:

```
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ConfigMap" in version "v1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Service" in version "v1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ServiceAccount" in version "v1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml": no matches for kind "ServiceAccount" in version "v1"
```

My kubectl version output is:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-17T18:53:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Would appreciate any help, even some advice for self debugging. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like something is gravely sick about the API; what are the logs from the `apiserver` container, as well as `kubelet` (likely running in systemd, so `journalctl -u kubelet.service`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use separate ranges for your pod-network-cidr and apiserver-advertise-address as it is stated in this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903123/kubernetes-set-service-cidr-and-pod-cidr-the-same)
Please try to remove the cluster and reinit it again with different network configuration:

Start with:

> Run this to revert any changes made to this host by 'kubeadm init' or
>   'kubeadm join'.
>
> ```
> kubeadm reset
> ```

Then init the cluster again (IP address is a safe example).

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=10.0.0.20
```

Also if you are running that as in the tutorial you've linked on the master node you can skip --apiserver-advertise-address as it uses the default gateway of the current machine.

Run the standard commands from the kubeadm [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

> To make kubectl work for your non-root user, run these commands,
>   which are also part of the  `kubeadm init`  output:

`mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`

> Alternatively, if you are the  `root`  user, you can run:

`export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

After that install the network add-on:
For [Calico](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/):

> In order for Network Policy to work correctly, you need to pass 
>   `--pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`  to  `kubeadm init`. Note that
>   Calico works on  `amd64`  only.

`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/rbac-kdd.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml`

You can also start from scratch with official [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/) on how to install kubeadm.

Comment: export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf         fixed my same issue thank you

Answer (score 7):

If kubernete version is above 1.16 then please use to following link to install calico.

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.9/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Please check the node status to confirm if calico is installed successfully.
[image]

coredns and calico should be in running state.

[image]